# Bootstrap: Navbar Item Stuck on Active State After Scrolling To Another Item?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to JavaScript and learning using a bootstrap template. The problem I'm having is that in my navigation bar, if I click on an item, then start scrolling, that item still remains active even though I've scrolled to another item as seen here:

[image]

If I clicked on About, then scroll to Portfolio, About still remains Active.

I'm not sure the relevant code needed to assist me, but based on looking, I noticed these codes in my main.css:

```
.navbar-default a.navbar-brand:link, .navbar-default a.navbar-brand:visited
{
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default a.navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default a.navbar-brand:active
{
    color: #12bebd;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active > a:focus
{
    color: #12bebd;
    background: none;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus
{
    background-color: #12bebd;
}
```

I also noticed in the provided jquery.nav.js:

```
//Handle clicks on the nav
self.$nav.on('click.onePageNav', $.proxy(self.handleClick, self));

...

handleClick: function(e) {
            var self = this;
            var $link = $(e.currentTarget);
            var $parent = $link.parent();
            var newLoc = '#' + self.getHash($link);

            if(!$parent.hasClass(self.config.currentClass)) {
                //Start callback
                if(self.config.begin) {
                    self.config.begin();
                }

                //Change the highlighted nav item
                self.adjustNav(self, $parent);

                //Removing the auto-adjust on scroll
                self.unbindInterval();

                //Scroll to the correct position
                $.scrollTo(newLoc, self.config.scrollSpeed, {
                    axis: 'y',
                    easing: self.config.easing,
                    offset: {
                        top: -self.config.scrollOffset
                    },
                    onAfter: function() {
                        //Do we need to change the hash?
                        if(self.config.changeHash) {
                            window.location.hash = newLoc;
                        }

                        //Add the auto-adjust on scroll back in
                        self.bindInterval();

                        //End callback
                        if(self.config.end) {
                            self.config.end();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        },
```

If I comment out `self.$nav.on('click.onePageNav', $.proxy(self.handleClick, self));`, the item becomes inactive when I scroll away, but I dont get that scrolling animation effect.

I'm sure it's fairly simple. How can I resolve this or where can I look in my code?

Comment: hi can you create jsfiddle?  or live example link?

Comment: hey i can't see that at a time only one link active

Comment: please click on a link, then scroll the page, you will see the link you clicked remains active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,` from this part of your CSS:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active > a:focus
{
    color: #12bebd;
    background: none;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}
```

and add as independed part of code (new property & value):

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
   color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS should fix it. Make sure it's loaded after the bootstrap CSS though.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
   color: #fff;
```

}

Comment: this is equivalent to me commenting out the code `self.$nav.on('click.onePageNav', $.proxy(self.handleClick, self));` It fixes the problem, but causes another problem as I dont achieve that scrolling animation when I click a Nav-Bar item.